# A dragon in a Markov chain on a triangle

Tags: probability, markov-chains

There is a dragon sitting on a vertex of a triangle (say, $A, B, C$ are its vertices, a dragon is on $A$). It's equally likely for a dragon to stay on a vertex or to go to one of the other two. I need to find the mean number of steps for a dragon to return to the initial vertex. There is an assumption: if a dragon stays at $A$, then it's counted as 1 step.

I was trying to do the same thing as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818737/find-the-mean-number-of-steps-in-a-markov-chain), left eigenvector (the one that describes stationary distribution) for this Markov matrix (3x3 with $\frac{1}{3}$ on each position) is $\pi=(1,1,1)$, so is the mean number of steps is $1$, but I'm not sure.

I also tried to make the same derivation from algebraic set of equation for $E_i, i=1,2,3,4$, which is the mean number of steps to reach vertex $1$ from vertex $i$, but with my assumption $E_1=1$, not $0$, so I failed.

Comment: The "drunkard dragon path"...

Comment: Eigenvector should be a probability vector, all components are probabilities and should sum to $1$, not $3$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri oh yeah, my bad, then it's components are 1/3 and the answer must be 3, right?

Comment: Is the answer any different if it's a unicorn instead of a dragon? I like unicorns....

Comment: @GerryMyerson I _am_ a unicorn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to check that the Markov chain is irreducible aperiodic and has unform stationary distribution, so the hitting time at any vertex is simply the reciprocal of $\frac13$, i.e. $3$.